# Executing multiple commands using Net::SSH::Perl module

Tags: perl, ssh, perl-module

I am new to this module. I tried a sample program and it worked fine. But, now I would like to how do I execute multiple commands in this program :

```
use Net::SSH::Perl;
my $hostname = "<<hostname>>";
my $username = "<<username>>";
my $password = "<<password>>";

my $cmd = 'mkdir script; cd script';

my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new("$hostname", debug=>0);
$ssh->login("$username","$password");

my ($stdout,$stderr,$exit) = $ssh->cmd("$cmd");
print $stdout;
```

Comment: Have you tried calling `$ssh->cmd` several times?

Comment: Maybe a bit lame, but you can always concatenate all commands on one line and put that in $cmd

Answer (score 0):

You can just call `cmd` repeatly.

The problem you are facing may be that every command is run in a different shell and commands that are run for their side effects as `cd` or `export` become useless.

As a work around you can prefix all the commands with the `cd $dir` command. For instance:

```
my ($stdout1, $stderr1, $exit1) = $ssh->cmd("cd /$dir && $cmd1");
my ($stdout2, $stderr2, $exit2) = $ssh->cmd("cd /$dir && $cmd2");
...
```

Another option is to run a shell on the remote host and talk to it, but this is more difficult and error prone.

Finally, Net::SSH::Perl is old and unmaintained, nowadays, [Net::SSH2](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aSSH2) or [Net::OpenSSH](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aOpenSSH) are usually better options.